# Cast Object Dynamically

Tags: java, object, casting

I am currently working with JavaFx. I need to make shapes and then add a click event which will open a new window which will take inputs to change the size of the shape. 
I have a parent Class "MShape" and subclasses "MRectangle", "MCircle", "MEllipse" etc.
I have a method which creates these shapes polymorphically so their type is MShape. Here's the polymorphic code.

```
 public static MShape[] getDefaultShapes(){
    MShape[] allshapes= new MShape[7];
    allshapes[0] = new MRectangle( 255, 125, 30, 25);
    allshapes[1] = new MRectangle( 155, 75, 10, 40);
    allshapes[2] = new MCircle( 80, 80, 10);
    allshapes[3] = new MRectangle( 45, 105, 80, 40);
    allshapes[4] = new MCircle( 200, 100, 50);
    allshapes[5] = new MSquare (150, 200, 70);
    allshapes[6] = new MEllipse (50, 210, 30, 50);
    return allshapes;
}
```

Now, when I call this function in another class, I want to be able to cast the MShape into the corresponding shape. For example, I want to make a loop which will cast for example for the first index, MRectangle into an MRectangle. However, when I need to change from MRectangle to MEllipse, I dont want to use if-else statements. How should I cast it then?

Here's how I tried it:

```
public static void control(int index)
{
MShape[] shapes = MAllShapes.getDefaultShapes();
String shapeName=shapes[index].getClass().getSimpleName();
shapeName castedObject=(shapeName) shapes[index]
System.out.println(myShape.getName());
}
```

Comment: Why are you casting back to the original type in a loop? That sounds fairly suspect.

Comment: The cast in and of itself is a smell. Why do you need to cast the shapes back? If you need different shapes, why do you group them together?

Comment: As a thumb rule, if you need class specific behavior (for which you want to determine what is the type of child class), you should wrap it in an abstract method / interface and let child classes implement it. Remember, program to interface, not to class.

Comment: They are different shapes but all are subclass of the class MShape which gives these shapes their coordinates to display on the screen. I need to cast them back so I can use the setX and setY methods on them which I can't achieve without casting them :/

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - Move `setX`1 and `setY` to `MShape` as abstract methods that `MRectangle` etc. implement appropriately.

Comment: @Anon what exactly should I wrap in the abstract method?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer, Look at T.J's answer. If you move setX and setY to abstract method / interface, then you do not need to worry about which child class it is because all child classes will implement the method.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - You haven't given us enough information to answer that. But the fundamental point is: If you have a loop iterating an array of `MShape`s and performing a common operation on them (but with differing details), you move that operation to `MShape` instead, and then implement the details in the concrete subclasses. See my updated answer for a (er) concrete example.

Comment: (Muhammad - This was a good question to ask. Learning how to deal with this is very useful to you long-term.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment, it's fairly suspect to be casting back to the original type in a loop. It suggests that `MShape` isn't doing its job. I'll come back to this in a moment, but first:

> I dont want to use if-else statements

That's your only option (`if` or other similar control-flow branching mechanisms), if you really mean that you want to *cast* the references you have back to the type of the object they refer to. And it'll be a fairly ugly set of branches, too.

Getting back to `MShape` not doing its job. Without knowing *why* you want to cast back, it's impossible to say for sure, but suppose for instance the issue is that you want to render the shape and you need to use different methods on some renderer to do so:

```
// DON'T DO THIS
for (MShape shape in shapes) {
    if (shape instanceof MRectangle) {
        renderer.renderRectangle(/*...*/);
    } else if (shape instanceof MEllipsis) {
        renderer.renderEllipse(/*...*/);
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Instead, have `MShape` provide an abstract `render` method that accepts the renderer:

```
public abstract void renderTo(Renderer renderer);
```

...and then have the concrete classes implement it as appropriate:

```
// In MRectangle
public abstract void renderTo(Renderer renderer) {
    renderer.renderRectangle(/*...*/);
}

// In MEllipse
public abstract void renderTo(Renderer renderer) {
    renderer.renderEllipse(/*...*/);
}
```

Etc. Then your loop is:

```
for (MShape shape in shapes) {
    shape.renderTo(renderer);
}
```

It's worth noting that `Renderer` should be an *interface*, so that your classes can support multiple different kinds of target renderers.